# How to use variables in mysql table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I am a beginner of the program.
I am trying to use a PHP variable written in a MySQL table, but it is not recognized as a variable in PHP.

I made a table to test using this code

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
'id' INTEGER,
'col_1' TEXT
);
```

And insert data;

```
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('1', '$var');
```

I`ve tried to test using simple PHP code;

```
<?php 
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '1111';
$database = 'test_database';

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
$table = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) {
$var = 1;
echo $rows['col_1'];
}
?>
```

I expected the result will be '1' but actual result was '$var'.
How can MySQL data be recognized as a PHP variable?

Comment: Where are you printing/using `$var`?

Comment: "I expected the result will be '1' but actual result was '$var'." Its not clear.

Comment: `$var` is written in the mysql table in a 'col_1' column. And I defined `$var` as '1' in PHP. I thought if I echo `$row['col_1']` the result will be '1'. However the result was '$row' not '1'.

Comment: That will be a comedy. Db is to a place where you set variable, its to save data's set to variables etc. A database is a collection of information that is organized so that it can be easily accessed, managed and updated. ... *Databases* process workloads to create and update themselves, querying the *data* they contain and running applications against it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
echo $rows['col_1'];
```

use like this

```
$result=$query->result_array();
echo $result;
```